# How does cnosdb handle out-of-order data?

Tags: cnosdb

Handling out-of-order data is crucial for time-series databases because data usually doesn't come in time order. Due to network latency or the processing capacity of IoT devices, data may be transmitted in batches. Flink, for example, has added watermarks to increase fault tolerance for out-of-order data.

Does cnosdb have a similar concept to optimize the processing of out-of-order data?